# Clion Cmake Static Library link -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm using centos 8
Gcc

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --disable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4) (GCC)
```

My CMake [UPDATED]

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(TestProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=c++17")
add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

#--------------- Static Includes -----------------
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
set(PHTREADS_LIB "-lphreads")
#----- Include Curl
set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(TestProject ${CURL_LIBRARIES}  ${PHTREADS_LIB})
```

The issue [UPDATED

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lphreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build.make:84: TestProject] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/rule] Error 2
```

My main goal is to try to add (libgcc libstdc++) as static.

Can someone guide me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ```[root@centos8dev ~]# find /usr/lib* -name 'libstdc++*.a'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++fs.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32/libstdc++fs.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.a```

Comment: You could do the same search for `libm.a` and `libc.a` just to make sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Aside from a couple antiquated CMake idioms in your CMake file, the call to `target_link_libraries()` references `TestProject` before it is even defined, that should be an error. Is there no error about this?

Comment: Good point, I move add_executable(TestProject main.cpp) up to be defined. but still not answer my question

Comment: Okay so now as you said define the TestProject add those 2 error, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lphreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Can you please provide the **full** output from the CMake log when you run `cmake`? Perhaps, CMake cannot find the Curl library.

Comment: Instead of manually linking `-lpthreads` via the `PTHREADS_LIB` variable I would add `Threads::Threads` to your `target_link_libraries` call. This also sets necessary defines for the compiler and adds the include directories.

Comment: Same goes for `CURL::libcurl` instead of a manual linking. Please see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) for these calls.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok found the issue for -lm -lc (missing install glibc-static)

Comment: Great! If you can post an Answer explaining this, and any necessary CMake modifications showing what worked for you, it will benefit future visitors to your question post.

Comment: I still not get all working  down but I will post what I done

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

Missing glibc-static

Centos 8

```
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install glibc-static
or
yum install glibc-static

for libstdc++

dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install libstdc++-static
or 
yum install libstdc++-static
```

Centos 7

```
yum install glibc-static
```

Include Threads

```
#----- Include phtread
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Threads::Threads)
```

Include Curl [FIX]

Here is more complicated for Centos 8

Zlib

```
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install zlib-static
```

CMake Include Zlib

```
add_library(
        libz
        STATIC IMPORTED
)
set_target_properties(
        libz
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        /usr/lib64/libz.a
)
```

Install Static Lib

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.0.tar.gz

tar -xvf curl-7.61.0.tar.gz

cd curl-7.61.0/
```

Set Config

```
./configure --disable-debug --disable-ftp --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --disable-rtsp --disable-proxy --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smb --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-manual --disable-ipv6 --disable-sspi --disable-crypto-auth --disable-ntlm-wb --disable-tls-srp --without-nghttp2 --without-libidn2 --without-libssh2 --without-brotli --with-zlib --without-ssl

for SSL ( --with-ssl  required openssl-static (not availabe for Centos 8 ) )
```

Install

```
make && make install
```

Cmake Changes

```
add_library(
        libz
        STATIC IMPORTED
)
set_target_properties(
        libz
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        /usr/lib64/libz.a
)


target_link_libraries(TestProject libcurl libz Threads::Threads)
```